# MSK (Kafka) IAM Authentication and Terraform

Tags: apache-kafka, terraform, aws-msk

I am attempting to Terraform the Kafka topics on a MSK cluster.

The requirements are that it is set up for IAM access control and not SASL/SCRAM.

My question is, Is it possible to use the Terraform provider (https://github.com/Mongey/terraform-provider-kafka) with IAM access control? Most of the examples I have seen online focus on Java, whereas Terraform is using a Golang library to talk to Kafka. The Java examples seem to use a JAR library. Does anything exist for Golang to do similar and is there any way to use it with the Terraform provider?

Comment: Not sure who it is that flagged this for closure, but maybe you could comment and give me guidance on how to better formulate the question than hide anonymously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Terraform provider does not support authentication MSK via IAM, see https://github.com/Mongey/terraform-provider-kafka/issues/218

Comment: OpenTelemetry did it, though, if you refer to the issue. That won't help with terraform though since that's pre compiled

Comment: @conor-mongey when this opened issue will be resolved? I feel, It could be a most requested feature as of now when we terraform AWS MSK.